# What kind of Machine Learning Problem it is if we have to Predict customer next spend category in python?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, classification, regression

I have a data set of shape -> `(6210782, 5)`.

This has `200,000 unique customers` and their transactions at different different outlets.  Time Series is little over an year.

```
df.head()

customer_id TransactionDate TransationTime  Amount  OutletCategory
514         22-04-2015      19:42:18        9445    M16
514         23-04-2015      16:29:28        2000    M23
514         02-05-2015      15:17:55        1398    M16
514         27-06-2015      13:51:29        1995    M7
514         07-08-2015      17:31:30        2000    M23
```

**What Kind of Machine Learning Problem it is and what should be the approach and algorithm used in solving following tasks:**

1) `predict customers Next Transaction category`? 
(I am thinking of this as multinomial classification)

2) `predict customers Next Transaction category in next 6 hrs`?

3) `predict customers Next Transaction Amount`?
(Is this an LSTM task)

4) `predict customers Next Transaction Amount in next 6 hrs`?

As we have 200,000 unique customers how should I prepare the data if I have to predict the next transaction amount ? Should I pivot the customers to columns???

---

**Data/ Time Series Exploration that may help visualize the data:**

**Below is the Transactions Amount wrt to categories over the time series chart:**

[image]

`For below charts:` I have created a small data set of "Datetime" as index and "Amount" column to understand the transnational behavior wrt to time.

**Amount Spend to Transaction Dates chart:**

[image]

**Amount Spend to Weekly TransactionDates chart:**

[image]

**Mean of Amount spend in a day(hourly)**
[image]

---

**Expectations:**
I am new to Data Science and Python so just looking for right steps to proceed with the task (will manage the code myself)

Answer (score 2):

There will be never the exactly right answer to this kind of problem.

*To your problems:*

Everything related to 6 hours seems like to be a Timeseries problem. The works e.g. with Arima-Models.

3) Is a Regression, you basically have to predict a amount which has a wide range of possibilities. The starting point could be a linear-regression. But there are also other algorithms for that

1) Should be a multiclass problem, for this you could use a decision tree e.g.

*In general:*

To give you more ideas: Scikit-Learn https://scikit-learn.org/stable/ can be a good starting point for you.